# External display stopped working after system update

Tags: apt, grub2, nvidia, updates

Today I turned on my laptop and Ubuntu asked me to download some updates. I accepted, and after the installation a popup asked to reboot the system.

After system restart, I noticed that the external display was not working anymore. Going into screen settings it seems like only the main (laptop) display is detected.

Then I started checking for some pending update:

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/aslatter/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Hit:5 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fish-shell/release-3/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:8 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/shutter/ubuntu focal InRelease
Fetched 109 kB in 1s (146 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

$ sudo apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates 5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1+1 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1]
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-security,now 5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1+1]
```

I then ran `sudo apt upgrade` but it did not change anything, the package update is still pending. Then I tried to install the package manually:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04 : Depends: linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-49-generic (= 5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1+1) but it is not going to be installed
                                              Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.56) but 460.39-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is it possible that the issue is caused by the recent kernel update? I guess it went from 5.8.0.48 to 5.8.0.49:

```
$ find /boot/vmli*
/boot/vmlinuz
/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-48-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-49-generic
/boot/vmlinuz.old
```

I also tried to boot with 5.8.0.48 from Grub but I get stuck at login screen, the system completely freezes.

Any idea about how to solve?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can downgrade the `linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04` package (and all its dependencies) to the previous version (5.8.0-48.54~20.04.1) to solve that issue, that is caused because there's a broken dependency on the `linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.8.0-49.55~20.04.1+1)` package that ask for (depends on) `nvidia-kernel-common-460` package to be greater or equal to version 460.56 but only version 460.39 is available as of this moment. I hope that the package maintainer resolves this promptly.

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer. Will you link to some documentation on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]: this has been fixed by Ubuntu later the same day.

Ubuntu released a new kernel package linux-image-5.8.0-49-generic, but did not release all needed nvidia kernel driver packages (at least nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.56) is missing). Until this is fixed by Ubuntu, the Nvidia driver won't work with the new kernel. Boot the older Linux version linux-image-5.8.0-48-generic and it should still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after I updated my system,
after running `sudo apt list --upgradable`, I noticed nvidia on the list of upgradable packages and running
`sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` 
fixed my issue (I had assumed `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` should do it, but doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

You can try run the commands:

- sudo apt --fix-broken install
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade

I have had similar issues installing drivers and third-party apps. Most of the times I could fix like that, same kernel version, Ubuntu 20.04.