# Login screen hangs after upgrading to 5.8.0-49-generic

Tags: 20.04, kernel

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on a desktop, with dual monitor (just mentioning in case it matters). Everything works fine on 5.8.0-48-generic.

When I boot on 5.8.0-49-generic, the following happens:

- I get to the login screen, however it is showing on just one monitor, and at a low resolution.
- Keyboard and mouse are both none responsive (I think the mouse does respond for the first second or so, and then stops moving).

So basically the system is completely unusable. I have to boot on 5.8.0-48-generic to use it (and then it works fine again).

Any idea what's the issue? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Stay with the .48 kernel if that is what works for you.

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA card in your system?  Did you install the driver from the Ubuntu repos or from NVIDIA themselves?  The only reason I ask this is because the drivers from NVIDIA do not have the dkms driver installed with them so they do not carry over into newer kernel updates so you would have to reinstall the drivers every time you get a kernel update.

Comment: @David I think that's my fallback if I can't solve this issue :)

Comment: @Terrance I do have an Nvidia card (GeForce GTX 970).
I installed the drivers (nvidia-driver-460) via the Additional Drivers tab in the Software & Updates dialog.
Can't reinstall them on 5.8.0-49-generic (so don't know if that's the issue) as the keyboard and mouse aren't working either...

Comment: Can also add that keyboard and mouse don't work even in the recovery menu for 5.8.0-49-generic.

Comment: It sounds like something went wrong during the installation of the -49 kernel version.  I have installed it on 2 systems here without any problems.  I would suggest that you boot back to -48 kernel like @David has mentioned because even in the recovery menu it should be working.

Comment: Managed to fix it! (good tip @Terrance, that was indeed the issue)
Will write a detailed answer below in case someone else runs into this.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the issue was something in the Nvidia proprietary display driver (nvidia-driver-460) not carrying over to the new kernel. Thanks for the tip @Terrance :)

Here's what I did to fix:

- Boot back to 5.8.0-48-generic (by choosing "Advanced options for Ubuntu" at the GRUB boot menu).
- Open the Software & Updates dialog, go to Additional Drivers, choose the open source driver (the nouveau display driver) and Apply Changes.
- Once applied, reboot to 5.8.0-49-generic. Monitor, keyboard and mouse should be working now.
- Go back to the Additional Drivers tab, choose and apply the Nvidia proprietary display driver again. And that's it.

Comment: Could you please add some details for noobs? (1) How do you check the kernel version? (2) How do you boot back to an earlier verison?

Comment: @AturSams Sure. When you boot the computer and get to the grub menu (should look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCPLl.png), choose "Advanced options for Ubuntu". That will allow you to choose the kernel you're booting with. Edited the answer with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
I ended up needing to remove the nvidia driver:
`sudo apt purge nvidia*`
Afterwards I installed the driver fresh from the site.

To check your current kernel version:
Open a terminal and type `uname -r`.
If you see `5.8.0-49-generic` then you have the new(er) kernel version (As of April 14).
This seems to cause issues with the nvidia driver.
Please consider downloading the new nvidia driver from their website:
You can then add permission to run it and install it on your pc.
You might need to install gcc
`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. Kernel update from yesterday (April 14) from 5.8.0-48-generic to 5.8.0-49-generic caused problem with booting the graphical interface. When I run nvidia-smi, I get following output:

```
$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

I will follow-up as I solve the issue.

--

Edit (solved the problem): Found another thread and an explanation of what happened (mismatch of nvidia versions for the newly updated kernel -48 -> -49): https://askubuntu.com/a/1331291
I think the same applies also for the -50 version, as I had identical problem with that kernel as well.

I booted to the -48 kernel, which can show GUI but not in full quality as before (my 4k monitor does not work). I updated to the nvidia-kernel-common-460 (>= 460.56) via Synaptic package manager. The -48 was still stuck at the small resolution settings, and I found that somehow the `nvidia-driver-460` got removed on my system -- either by me trying out to reinstall things, or by the kernel update itself (I don't know).

After installing this package via Synaptic, both -48 and -50 work now!